# Firefox Gstreamer vaapi

Tags: firefox, gstreamer, vaapi

I have a laptop with not much CPU power, so I want that Firefox and Gstreamer (and maybe Rhythmbox) uses the VAAPI on my Ubuntu 15.10. vainfo gives me already the following output, so the vaapi driver seem to be working:

```
dennis@Yoda:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.38.1
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_38
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.38 (libva 1.6.2)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) CherryView - 1.6.2
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
```

I have tried many to get it work.....but it didn't worked.
It would be great, if somebody knews what to configurate now that firefox etc. uses the vaapi. (Everytime i install "gstreamer1.0-vaapi" gestreamer don't even shows me a Video)

Greets
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible, FireFox has no vaapi support (as far as I know). If it did you would have to install the h.264ify plugin to watch YouTube, because there is no hardware support for vp9 (the codec that YouTube uses) decoding.